# Qual foi o meu erro?

Tags: python

[image: Alguem sabe onde errei?]

Alguem sabe dizer / identificar o erro que cometi ? precisava mesmo de ajuda tou a comecar a aprender

Comment: Por favor clique em **[edit]** e coloque o código e a mensagem de erro como texto. Colocá-los como imagem não é o ideal, entenda os motivos [lendo o **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052). Mas *provavelmente* o problema é a identação do último `else`, que deveria estar alinhado com o `if`

Answer (score 2):

O último `else` que faz par com o último `if` deve ter a mesma indentação do `if`.